# SHOW CREATE TABLE

Tags: php, mysql

how can you put the database name in this syntax?

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE $table FROM $this->db
```

this still tells me:

> No database selected

Comment: Aren't you supposed to connect to the database first before trying to create tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try:

```
USE databasename;
```

Then read [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html) about `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (or other version, according to your needs)

Edit: Oh yes, of course in the context of PHP, use the [mysql_select_db function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) )

Answer (score 2):

You should select a database:

```
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db, $connection);
```

Comment: I always select the db in the query.. like: "SELECT * FROM db.table"

Answer (score 1):

Before you create a table, select a database:

```
USE dbname
```

Comment: "SHOW CREATE TABLE $table USE $this->db" ?? I was hoping not to select the db in another query

Answer (score 0):

Alternately:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `databasename`.`tablename`;
```

Comment: this still gives "No database selected": "SHOW CREATE TABLE $this->db.".$table[0]

Comment: @clarkk That is PHP code, not a query - what was the actual query produced by that code?